# Cannot use show dialog function inside fragment?

Tags: java, android

The problem in short is that I cannot use this function to show a dialog.

```
public class Page_6Fragment extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    List<Customer> customers;
    CustomerAdapter adapter;
    View rootView;
    String TAG = "MainActivity - ";
    Context context;
    API api;
    Activity a;
    public static Page_6Fragment newInstance() {
        Page_6Fragment fragment = new Page_6Fragment();
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_customer, container, false);
        //   View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.xml.pref, container, false);
        //  Intent intent = new Intent(PreferenceDemoActivity.this,PrefsActivity.class);
        // startActivity(intent);

        this.context = getActivity();
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        customers = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new CustomerAdapter(context, customers);

        adapter.setLoadMoreListener(new CustomerAdapter.OnLoadMoreListener(){
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore() {
                recyclerView.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        int index = customers.size() - 1;
                      loadMore(index);
                    }
                });
                //Calling loadMore function in Runnable to fix the
                // java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot call this method while RecyclerView is computing a layout or scrolling error
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
        //recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new VerticalLineDecorator(2));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        api = ServiceGenerator.createService(API.class);
        load(0);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void load(int index){
        Call<List<Customer>> call = api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, Response<List<Customer>> response){
            // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               // Log.i("TRUE_TRUE","Yes"+response.body().get(0).title);
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    customers.addAll(response.body());
                    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                    // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "tost "+response.body().get(0).post_writer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Response Error "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadMore(int index){
        //add loading progress view
        customers.add(new Customer("load"));
        adapter.notifyItemInserted(customers.size()-1);
        Call<List<Customer>>call =  api.getCustomer(index);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Customer>>(){
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Customer>> call, Response<List<Customer>>response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    // remove loading view .......
                    customers.remove(customers.size()-1);
                    List<Customer>result=response.body();
                    if(result.size()>0){
                        // add loaded data
                        customers.addAll(result);
                    }else{//result size 0 means there is no more data available at server
                        adapter.setMoreDataAvailable(false);
                        //telling adapter to stop calling load more as no more server data available
                        Toast.makeText(context,"No More Data Available",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataChanged();
                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG," Load More Response Error "+String.valueOf(response.code()));
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Customer>>call,Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG," Load More Response Error "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

public void showDialog(){
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
    dialog.setCancelable(true);
    View view  = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    dialog.show();
  }

}


// class to call function
package com.example.android.wacher.adapters;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.android.wacher.R;
import com.example.android.wacher.activities.HomeActivity;
import com.example.android.wacher.fragments.Page_6Fragment;
import com.example.android.wacher.models.Customer;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by cca on 23/12/2018.
 */

public class CustomerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    public final int TYPE_MOVIE = 0;
    public final int TYPE_LOAD = 1;

    static Context context;
    List<Customer> customers;
    OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener;
    boolean isLoading = false, isMoreDataAvailable = true;

    public CustomerAdapter(Context context, List<Customer> customers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.customers = customers;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if(viewType==TYPE_MOVIE){
            return new CustomerHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_movie,parent,false));
        }else{
            return new LoadHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_load,parent,false));
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        if(position>=getItemCount()-1 && isMoreDataAvailable && !isLoading && loadMoreListener!=null){
            isLoading = true;
            loadMoreListener.onLoadMore();
        }

        if(getItemViewType(position)==TYPE_MOVIE){
            ((CustomerHolder)holder).bindData(customers.get(position));

            if(((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption != null)((CustomerHolder)holder).buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    // call function 
                  Page_6Fragment.newInstance().showDialog();
                }
            });
        }
    }




    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if(customers.get(position).type.equals("movie")){
            return TYPE_MOVIE;
        }else{
            return TYPE_LOAD;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return customers.size();
    }

    /* VIEW HOLDERS */

    static class CustomerHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvTitle;
        TextView tvRating;
        Button buttonViewOption;

        public CustomerHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            tvTitle=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            tvRating=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
            buttonViewOption = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewOptions);
        }

        void bindData(Customer cust){
           tvTitle.setText(cust.name);
           tvRating.setText(cust.title);
        }
    }

    static class LoadHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        public LoadHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
        }
    }

    public void setMoreDataAvailable(boolean moreDataAvailable) {
        isMoreDataAvailable = moreDataAvailable;
    }

    /* notifyDataSetChanged is final method so we can't override it
         call adapter.notifyDataChanged(); after update the list
    */

    public void notifyDataChanged(){
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        isLoading = false;
    }


    public interface OnLoadMoreListener{
        void onLoadMore();
    }

    public void setLoadMoreListener(OnLoadMoreListener loadMoreListener) {
        this.loadMoreListener = loadMoreListener;
    }
}
```

When I call the `ShowDialog` function, an error occurs (pasted below.)

I don't know why this function does not work within the `Page_6Fragment` class.

```
Process: com.example.android.wacher, PID: 11335
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources$Theme android.content.Context.getTheme()' on a null object reference
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:173)
at android.app.Dialog.<init>(Dialog.java:147)
at com.example.android.wacher.fragments.Page_6Fragment.showDialog(Page_6Fragment.java:153)
at com.example.android.wacher.adapters.CustomerAdapter$1.onClick(CustomerAdapter.java:70)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5609)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22259)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Comment: I have edited your question for clarity. In the future, you should format your questions to be as readable as possible. You may also find that you get more help by including only the relevant portions of your code (enough that someone could test the reproduce the error for themselves.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `Page_6Fragment.newInstance().showDialog();` .
Method `public void showDialog()` should be `private` because of it's handle `Context` reference.
To show `Dialog` from else where you should use

```
public void showDialog(Context context){
   Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
   dialog.setCancelable(true);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.layout);
   dialog.show();
}
```

And no need to inflate layout to set content view

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: The one works, but if used private void showDialog() The function I can not call